# How could I set up an IDE (like VS Code, Sublime text 3) for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

I want to set up an `IDE` for `Python`. How could I do so?

I want to set up `Python` in code editor (like `VS Code`, `Sublime text 3`).  Currently I' m using `Jupyter Notebook`, which is not so efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please tell what IDE you want to set up. Also, don't go away with formatting. Check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think if you just google search it you'll get plenty of video tutorials to guide you. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question. Thanks.